# T-SQL GROUP BY: Eliminate multiple occurrences

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How can I prevent multiple identical price rows in the below query due to different date values? I only need to show the first occurrence of a record where price is different than the previous ones but skip until there is another change to the price field.

```
SELECT STOCKID, PRICE, TRANSTYPENAME, TRANSDATE
FROM VE_STOCKTRANS 
WHERE STOCKID = 6000 AND TANSTYPE IN (3500,3553)
GROUP BY PRICE, STOCKID, TRANSTYPENAME, TRANSDATE
```

i.e. I need to omit the multiple 35.83333333 rows and only take the first occurrence of it (24/4/2018)

[image]

Image reply to Gordon's Answer:

[image]

Comment: Why are you grouping by when you don't have to run any aggregation on the same? just use distinct price instead?

Comment: DISTINCT works if I don't output the TRANSDATE which in my case is required. On the other hand, I am at a very beginner level with TSQL so If you have anything in mind please let me know

Comment: Add the TRANSTYPE column to the PARTITION BY clause of Gordon's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get first TRANSDATE like that:

```
SELECT STOCKID, PRICE, TRANSTYPENAME, min(TRANSDATE)
FROM VE_STOCKTRANS 
WHERE STOCKID = 6000 AND TRANSTYPE IN (3500,3553)
GROUP BY PRICE, STOCKID, TRANSTYPENAME
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `LAG()` to see if the price changed:

```
SELECT STOCKID, PRICE, TRANSTYPENAME, TRANSDATE
FROM (SELECT st.*,
             LAG(st.price) OVER (PARTITION BY stockId ORDER BY transdate) as prev_price
      FROM VE_STOCKTRANS st
      WHERE STOCKID = 6000 AND TANSTYPE IN (3500, 3553)
     ) st
WHERE prev_price IS NULL OR prev_price <> price;
```

EDIT:

If you just want a list of the first time that each price is seen (which is quite different from changes in prices, as you have noted and described in the question), use `row_number()`:

```
SELECT STOCKID, PRICE, TRANSTYPENAME, TRANSDATE
FROM (SELECT st.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY st.stockId, st.price ORDER BY st.transdate) as seqnum
      FROM VE_STOCKTRANS st
      WHERE STOCKID = 6000 AND TANSTYPE IN (3500, 3553)
     ) st
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon. Please check my updated question, I still get identical prices for different dates.

Comment: @KemalEmin . . . Because the value changes *back* to that price.   Do you just want a list of unique prices?

Comment: Yes Gordon. @Radu already answered. Thank you very much for sparing time for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT STOCKID, DISTINCT(PRICE), TRANSTYPENAME, TRANSDATE)
FROM VE_STOCKTRANS 
WHERE STOCKID = 6000 AND TANSTYPE IN (3500,3553)
GROUP BY PRICE, STOCKID, TRANSTYPENAME, TRANSDATE
```

This might helps..